# How can share IPA to download without AppStore & UDID

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipa

I'm developer agent, so what i do to share IOS application to download via HTTPS without appstore & udid
??

I'm already Archive my app and exporting to downloads on devices that i had registered in my profile!

Can i do it?

Comment: You can only distribute an app via the app store. You have the option to use the enterprise distribution to distribute your app but there are limit, like you are only allowed to distribute it you employees of you company.  There is no way around it unless you use a jailbroke device.

Comment: I'm already distribute my apps and upload to my website, but only device that I'm insert UDID is downloaded successfully!, I need to share free apps to download without UDID

Answer (score 0):

You can build your app and sign with distribution cert and share among your testers via iTunes TestFlight. Another way is to buy and distribute app via in-house Enterprise Program [read more](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterpris)